# What is the influence on CosmosDB RUs when using projections in MongoAPI queries

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I can't find any information on wether "[item size](https://cosmos.azure.com/capacitycalculator/)" refers to the original document size, or to the result size of the query after projection.

I can observe that simple queries like these

```
 documents.find({ /*...*/ }, { name: 1 })
```

consume more than 1000 RU, for results of 400 items (query fields are indexed). The original documents are pretty large, about 500 kb. The actually received data is tiny due to the projection. If I remove the projection, the query runs several seconds but doesn't consume significantly more RUs (it's actually slightly more, but it seems to be due to the fact that it's split into more `GetMore` calls).

[image]

It sounds really strange to me, that the cost of a query mainly depends on the size of the original document in the collection, not on the data retrieved. Is that really true? Can I redruce the cost of this query without splitting data into multiple collections? The logic is basically: "Just get the 'name' of all these big documents in the collection".

(No partitioning on the db...)

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "simple queries" - you didn't show the type of `find()` operation you're executing, or how you set up indexes. It would probably be helpful to edit your question and share more details.

Comment: Also, unclear what you mean by "no partitioning on the db" - how are you avoiding partitioning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft unfortunately doesn't seem to publish their formula for determining RU costs, just broad descriptions. They do say about [RU considerations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/request-units#request-unit-considerations):

> As the size of an item increases, the number of RUs consumed to read
> or write the item also increases

So it is the case that cost depends on the raw size of the item, not just the portion of it output from a read operation. If you use the Data Explorer to run some queries and inspect the Query Stats, you'll see two metrics, `Retrieved Document Size` and `Output Document Size`. By projecting a subset of properties, you reduce the output size, but not the retrieved size. In tests on my data, I see a very small decrease in RU charge by selecting the return properties -- definitely not a savings in proportion to the reduced output.

Fundamentally, getting items smaller is probably the most important thing to work towards, both in terms of the property data size and the number of properties. You definitely don't want 500 KB items if you can avoid it.

Comment: `You definitely don't want 500 KB items if you can avoid it.` in terms of costs, or is that a general advice? I don't see a point of not storing the whole document in a document based DB. All queries, commands, aggregations work perfectly fine and performant, they're just too expensive. But thanks a lot for your answer ;) I will ask the MS team why a query that runs a few ms costs the same as the query that runs 100 times longer...

Comment: "They're just too expensive". That's fundamentally true the larger your items are, no matter what else you try to optimize. If you don't care about expense, then nothing to worry about as long as you don't hit the 2 MB item limit.